# Caching over distributed application on servers

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing, distributed-caching

I have a web application that will be distributed over 2 servers and the Database will be on a server other than the 2 servers. so application on each server will access database exists in another server.I am using caching in the application and when data changed the cache is cleared and the problem now how each server will feel with cache changes on the other server?

I have tried SQLCache dependency before and i have heard about Memcached, Velocity and Enterprise cache so which one will be more efficient and optimal for this case? and i have another solution to create webservice method on each application and when the cache is cleared in one application it will request the webservice method on the other application to clear cache there.

Which technique is more efficient and optimal in performance and security? and is SQLCache dependency related to SQL database only or can be applicable to other databases like Oracle?

Note: I am using load balancer to distribute requests coming for the application among the 2 server

Thanks in advance

Comment: Theres a solution for java: Terracotta (http://www.terracotta.org) I dont know if something like this exists for asp.net.

Comment: No thanks i am not using java but if these techniques are common in java and .net so feel free to discuss the characteristics of each one.